# If selected value exist in list (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, select, html-lists, each

I have an empty ul and select,

```js
$(document).on("change", "#ogppropoc-select", function() {
  var i = $(this).val();
  if ($("#recipient-list li").length != 0) {
    $("#recipient-list li").each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() != i) {
        $("#recipient-list").append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#recipient-list").append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="ogppropoc-select" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<ul id="recipient-list"></ul>
```

When a number is selected from select, it is added into the recipient-list. But if a number is selected that already exists on the recipient-list, it shouldn't be added into the list.

This jQuery code adds number but it doesn't control if there is same number on the list. So I can add same numbers again and again.

Briefly, my goal is every number should exist on the list just once.

Answer (score 2):

I'd shorten your code to the following. The way it works is that when an option is chosen, it adds a data attribute to it. The code first checks to see if the attribute exists and if it doesn't, it appends the chosen option to your list.

```js
$(document).on("change", "#ogppropoc-select", function() {
  if (!$(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').data('used')) $("#recipient-list").append('<li>' + this.value + '</li>');
  $(this).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').data('used', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="ogppropoc-select" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<ul id="recipient-list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Search if there is already that value, if not then Insert one.

---

**Something Like this:**

```js
$(document).on("change", "#ogppropoc-select", function() {
  var i = $(this).val();
  if (!$("#recipient-list li[value='"+i+"']").length) {
    $("#recipient-list").append('<li value="'+i+'">' + i + '</li>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="ogppropoc-select" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected>Choose...</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<ul id="recipient-list"></ul>
```

---

### Your Issue with the code

You have one Failing If else Condtition

```
$(document).on("change", "#ogppropoc-select", function() {
  var i = $(this).val();
  if ($("#recipient-list li").length != 0) {
    // let's say you have selected 1,2,3 and again selected 1
    $("#recipient-list li").each(function() {
      // when i = 1 => Does nothing
      // when i = 2 => Adds Duplicate
      // when i = 3 => Adds Duplicate
      if ($(this).text() != i) {
        $("#recipient-list").append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $("#recipient-list").append('<li>' + i + '</li>');
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes that code very simple and works, but can you say that where the problem is in my code.

Comment: @u238 You have failing if condition, I have updated the answer to show where the problem is. And you can accept the answer if it meets what you seek.